# No IMAP. No POP. Am I stuck with Outlook?

Tags: windows, email, exchange

I have an exchange account. The email server does not accept POP/IMAP.  I want to get rid of Outlook and not use some weird way using Outlook Web Access to get emails into a client.

Is there a Windows Email client that can connect to an exchange server?

If there isn't how is it possible that mobile devices like iPhone/Android can write an exchange client that works perfectly?

Comment: "how is it possible that mobile devices...can work perfectly" They use ActiveSync, not binary MAPI or Outlook RPC. ActiveSync costs money.

Comment: The Evolution email client can access Exchange through [OWA](http://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-exchange/), [MAPI](http://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-mapi/), and the newest [EWS](http://git.gnome.org/browse/evolution-ews/). Good luck on finding a Windows build of any of these, though... Getting the admins enable IMAP would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://davmail.sourceforge.net/ - its an Exchange "Proxy" which gives you imap access. It runs over OWA so you are synced with Exchange.

Comment: I said I didn't want to use that kind of thing

Comment: Sorry read that you don't want to get mails via OWA (website). So i didn't found an client which is fully exchange capable without this OWA Access.